# Insert Multiple Images As Comments Into Multiple Cells Using VBA Giving Subscript Out Of Range Error (9)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting the subscript out of range (error 9) when trying to insert multiple images into a comment in multiple cells. The idea of the VBA code is for me to be able to select multiple cells in workbook, then select multiple images, and it will add the images in order as a comment to each cell in order.

In order to do this I first try to go through the selected images in the file dialog window with a For loop and add them to the TheFile array. Then I try to use another For loop to add the image in the array position of j into the current cell and move on to the next cell and do the same.

Any idea what is causing the subscript out of range error? My code below:

```
Sub AddImageTo()

Dim TheFile() As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
         .AllowMultiSelect = True          'Only one file
         .InitialFileName = CurDir         'directory to open the window
         .Filters.Clear                    'Cancel the filter
         .Filters.Add Description:="Images", Extensions:="*.*", Position:=1
         .Title = "Choose image"

         If .Show = -1 Then
            For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            TheFile(i) = .SelectedItems(i)
            Next i
         Else: TheFile(1) = 0
         End If
End With
'No file selected
If TheFile(1) = 0 Then
MsgBox ("No image selected")
Exit Sub
End If

Set objImage = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    objImage.LoadFile TheFile

For j = 1 To UBound(TheFile)
For Each cell In Selection
    With ActiveCell
        .AddComment
        With .Comment
            With .Shape
                .Fill.UserPicture TheFile(j)
                .Height = objImage.Height * 0.45
                .Width = objImage.Width * 0.45
            End With
        End With
    End With
Next cell
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line errors?

Comment: Btw your loop only ever operates on the same cell as you don't reference `cell`.

Comment: Ah thanks, good point! I think the line that is giving me the error is "TheFile(i) = .SelectedItems(i)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is if you `Dim TheFile() As String` your array has no defined dimension and therefore you cannot access any item in the array like `TheFile(1) = 0`.

Here is an example on how to use the FileDialog for a multiselect

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .InitialFileName = CurDir             
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList  
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear 
    .Filters.Add Description:="Images", Extensions:="*.*", Position:=1
    .Title = "Choose image"
End With

Dim FileChosen As Integer 
FileChosen = fd.Show 'show dialog

If FileChosen = -1 Then

    Dim AddImagesRange As Range
    Set AddImagesRange = Selection

    'check if cells count matches files count
    If AddImagesRange.Cells.Count <> fd.SelectedItems.Count Then
        MsgBox "Count of seletced cells does not match count of images"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim i As Long:  i = 1
    Dim objImage As Object

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In AddImagesRange
        Set objImage = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
        objImage.LoadFile fd.SelectedItems(i)

        Cell.AddComment
        With Cell.Comment.Shape 'avoid cascaded with statements
            .Fill.UserPicture fd.SelectedItems(i)
            .Height = objImage.Height * 0.45
            .Width = objImage.Width * 0.45
        End With

        i = i + 1
        Set objImage = Nothing
    Next Cell

Else
    MsgBox ("No image selected")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried your solution, but now I'm getting an Application-defined or object-defined error (1004).

Do you know what could be causing this? I put everything after "For  Each Cell In Selection" into the part in your code that says do all the image stuff here.

Comment: As long as you don't tell in which line (or which code) you get an error we can not help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works as intended now and the check for the cell selection size matching the number of selected images is also a nice touch! Much appreciated!

Comment: @juleswhatevs you need to check the counts because if they don't match the code would throw an error and stop. So this was actually a *must have* here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub AddImageTo()

Dim TheFile() As String
Dim Cell As Range
Dim rngPic() As Range
Dim i As Integer, k As Integer, n As Integer, j As Integer

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
         .AllowMultiSelect = True          'Only one file
         .InitialFileName = CurDir         'directory to open the window
         .Filters.Clear                    'Cancel the filter
         .Filters.Add Description:="Images", Extensions:="*.*", Position:=1
         .Title = "Choose image"
         .Show
            For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
                k = k + 1
                ReDim Preserve TheFile(1 To k)
                    TheFile(k) = .SelectedItems(i)
                Next i
End With
'No file selected
If k = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("No image selected")
Exit Sub
End If

Set objImage = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    objImage.LoadFile TheFile(1)
For Each Cell In Selection
    n = n + 1
    ReDim Preserve rngPic(1 To n)
    Set rngPic(n) = Cell
Next Cell
For j = 1 To UBound(TheFile)
    If j > n Then Exit Sub
        With rngPic(j)
            .ClearComments
            .AddComment
            With .Comment
                With .Shape
                    .Fill.UserPicture TheFile(j)
                    .Height = objImage.Height * 0.45
                    .Width = objImage.Width * 0.45
                End With
            End With
        End With
Next j
End Sub
```